# remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal

I'm just getting started with Git/Github and I'm completely stuck. I'm using Terminal on Mac/OSX El Capitan and when it asks for password it tells me it is invalid, but I am entering the same password that I created for my GitHub account, so surely this should work? What am I doing wrong?

```
Last login: Sun Dec  4 10:46:35 on ttys000
Seans-MBP:~ mrseanbaines$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': mrseanbaines
Password for 'https://mrseanbaines@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten.git/'
Seans-MBP:~ mrseanbaines$
```

Comment: What does your remote look like (output of `git remote -v`)? Are you using two factor auth?

Comment: @yBot Last login: Sun Dec  4 11:51:27 on ttys000
Seans-MBP:~ mrseanbaines$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten.git (push)
Seans-MBP:~ mrseanbaines$ 

How do I check if I have two factor authentication enabled?

Comment: have you tried to login on github with those username/password?

Comment: @pedrorijo91 Yes, it works fine

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 39):

I had faced same issue.
Solution:
Step 1: Control Panel
Step 2: Credential Manager
Step 3: Click Window Credentials
Step 4: In Generic  Credential section ,there would be git url, edit and update username and password
Step 5: Restart Git Bash and try for clone
[image]

Comment: This works like a charm on a personal and corporate computer.

Comment: Legendary !!  Worked so well.

Answer (score 31):

Once you have enabled 2 Factor Authentication (2FA) on GitHub, you cannot use your GitHub password on the command line. Instead, you have to use a personal access token.

Personal access tokens are used to authenticate you for personal applications and on the command line. The command line does not tell us we need to generate a personal access token, which is why this solution is often overlooked by programmers.

Navigate to the “Settings” page
Click “Developer settings” in the sidebar
Click “Personal access tokens” in the sidebar
Click “Generate new token”
Fill in the form to create a new token

Use that token as password and git clone will work work

Comment: +1 for the above solution. After following the above steps original issue got fixed, but I had to go to Github and click on "Enable SSO" there we see "Authorize" button after I click that and later `git config --global credential.helper store` this helped to fix the annoying repetitively asking username in command line often

Answer (score 10):

**(1)** Go to https://github.com/settings/security , turn off **Two-factor authentication**.

**(2)** Create a new folder, inside the new folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten.git
cd cartwheeling-kitten
```

Open empty source code directory, since you use macOS, type

```
open .
```

**(3)** Copy your source code to folder **cartwheeling-kitten** (it's the opening folder)

**(4)** Config

```
git config user.name "Your full name"
git config user.email "Your_email_address_what_used_to_register Github_account"
```

**(5)** Add remote URL

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten.git
```

**(6)** Add to stage, then push

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "Upload source code"
git push -u origin master
```

**(7)** Go to https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten see result.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but after the 'git push -u origin master' it asks me for username and password. Looks like this:

https://snag.gy/cqNOts.jpg

...and the GitHub page still looks like this:

https://snag.gy/nhKacb.jpg

After I enter the password it goes to the next line without the "Seans-MBP:" and nothing seems to happen, but if I try to close the terminal, it seems as though it is in the middle of doing something. Looks like this:

https://snag.gy/t1q9lv.jpg

Answer (score 5):

2020 - When you change your password on Github and after in your local machine it will complain about credentials but you can easily fix it doing a `git pull` which will force asking you the credentials. So you type the new one and be happy :).

Answer (score 1):

If you already have setup SSH key in your system for some other git account then just do these steps https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

and check activation using `ssh -T git@github.com`
if you see 'Hi GitAccountUserName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.'

Then continue your previous work.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to push the code into remote repo from local (macbook), I faced the same issue after PASSWORD reset on GHE website.

$ **git push -u origin coffee_shop_autorization**

remote: Invalid username or password.

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/ravinderreddy-p/FSND.git/'

Then I followed below simple steps to fix this issue:

1. I cloned another repository from GHE to local in different folder:

   **git clone https://github.com/ravinderreddy-p/bookshelf.git**
2. I switched to this folder by '**cd bookshelf**'
3. I tried to push the same without making any changes as below:

   **git push**
4. It prompted for Username for 'https://github.com':<**Provide your GHE user name**> then press enter.
5. It prompted as Password for 'https://ravinderreddy-p@github.com': <**provide 
   updated password on GHE**> then press enter
6. You will see this message as "**Everything up-to-date"**

All Done.

Now go to your previous local repo where you tried to push the code into remote and execute your previous command

**git push -u origin coffee_shop_autorization**

It will push the code into remote repo and you can see similar as below (with your repo and branch details):

Enumerating objects: 35, done.

Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.

Delta compression using up to 4 threads

Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.

Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 2.47 KiB | 843.00 KiB/s, done.

Total 15 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 5 local objects.

remote:

remote: Create a pull request for 'coffee_shop_autorization' on GitHub by visiting:

remote:      https://github.com/ravinderreddy-p/FSND/pull/new/coffee_shop_autorization

remote:

To https://github.com/ravinderreddy-p/FSND.git

- [new branch]      coffee_shop_autorization -> coffee_shop_autorization
  Branch 'coffee_shop_autorization' set up to track remote branch 'coffee_shop_autorization' from 'origin'.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows.  I have not enabled 2FA, merely changed my password.  None of the other upvoted solutions given here were applicable.  Strange (and disappointingly poor) that pushing with changes failed, whereas pushing without changes brought up a login dialog.  Also poorly, after selecting "log in via browser" I ended up at a page saying "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:49217".  Well, obviously not.  But I was authenticated by then and able to push my changes.  Windows and GitHub are made by the same company; you'd expect them to work together.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your remote urls are correct. It looks like you're missing the protocol, it should be: `https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten.git`. You can verify this by cloning the repo to another directory, and trying git operations there.

If you want to fix it to add the protocol, you can do: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/mrseanbaines/cartwheeling-kitten.git`